# Why do I get "TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found" using `ord` on binary data in 3.x?

Tags: python, typeerror, ord

I have some code like:

```
import os, struct, time

# Create a packet by building it with a dummy checksum first,
# then computing and replacing the checksum field.
myChecksum = 0
pid = os.getpid() & 0xFFFF
header = struct.pack("bbHHh", ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST, 0, myChecksum, pid, 1)
data = struct.pack("d", time.time())
csum = 0
countTo = (len(str) / 2) * 2
count = 0

while count < countTo:
    thisVal = ord(str[count+1]) * 256 + ord(str[count])
    csum = csum + thisVal
    csum = csum & 0xffffffff
    count = count + 2
# Further logic to compute the replace the dummy checksum within the data
```

But at the line that computes `thisVal`, I get an error like so:

```
    thisVal = ord(str[count+1]) * 256 + ord(str[count])
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Baffling! If you can reproduce this, try printing `repr(str)` at the start of `checksum()`.

Answer (score 56):

`struct.pack` produces raw binary data. In Python 3.x, this is represented by the `bytes` type; in 2.x, `bytes` is an alias for `str`.

In Python 3, indexing a `bytes` object returns the integer value of the byte:

```
>>> b"abc"[1]
98
```

Thus, the `ord` calls are redundant in the original code, and should be removed.

Comment: Good guess!  If they are running Python3, they should also change `(len(str) / 2) * 2` to use integer division (or simply `&` off the last bit).

Comment: @TimPeters Could you please explain it well , what has to be changed.

Comment: @user2977469 use `//` instead of `/` for integer division - it works in recent versions of Python 2 as well.

Comment: In Python 3, "3/2" is "1.5", for example. Your `checksum()` function expects it to return the integer 1 instead (which happens in Python 2).  The fastest fix is to change `/` to `//` in the `countTo = (len(str) / 2) * 2`.  If you don't, your function won't work correctly for strings of odd length.

Comment: @TimPeters thanks, and i tried using len(str)//2 and even countTo = (len(str) // 2) * 2 but still i get the same error

Comment: @user2977469: have you removed `ord` calls?

Comment: @user2977469, are you, or are you not, using Python 3?  Either switch to Python 2, or remove the `ord` calls *and* fix the division.

Comment: @TimPeters  I changed ord and now the program works but i only get request timed out as output.

Comment: @jfs Just to clarify: In python2, one needs `ord()`, but in python3, one simply omits it for the same input string? Thanks! and, why?

Comment: @jfs amazing..!