# python3 error ord() expected string of length 1. python2.7 is fine

Tags: python

I got an error while using the below codes `TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found` when I used python3.5 while python2.7 is fine. How can I fix it?

*example.py

```
import binascii

h = '0020701a8d401c84fb13e6baf169d59684e17abd9fa216c8cc5b9fc63d622ff8c58d'
b = binascii.unhexlify(h)

a = [ord(x) for x in b]

print(a)
```

*python2.7

```
$ python example.py
[0, 32, 112, 26, 141, 64, 28, 132, 251, 19, 230, 186, 241, 105, 213, 150, 132, 225, 122, 189, 159, 162, 22, 200, 204, 91, 159, 198, 61, 98, 47, 248, 197, 141]
```

*python3.5

```
$ python3 example.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 6, in <module>
    a = [ord(x) for x in b]
  File "example.py", line 6, in <listcomp>
    a = [ord(x) for x in b]
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

---

update 1

I removed "ord" then it worked.

```
import binascii

h = '0020701a8d401c84fb13e6baf169d59684e17abd9fa216c8cc5b9fc63d622ff8c58d'
b = binascii.unhexlify(h)

a = [x for x in b]

print(a)
```

---

update 2

@PM 2Ring gave me one more suggestion. I use "list(b)"

```
import binascii

h = '0020701a8d401c84fb13e6baf169d59684e17abd9fa216c8cc5b9fc63d622ff8c58d'
b = binascii.unhexlify(h)

print(list(b))
```

Comment: [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897209/troubleshooting-typeerror-ord-expected-string-of-length-1-but-int-found)

Comment: In Python 3 `unhexlify` returns a `bytes` string. So you don't need `ord`, you can just iterate over the bytes to get the integers, or pass it to `list()`. In fact, you don't even need `unhexlify` in recent versions, `bytes` has a constructor that takes hex.

Comment: @Paul. Since the accepted answer for the post you linked can serve word for word as the answer to this question, I've closed this as a duplicate.

Comment: BTW, `[x for x in b]` is a slow way of doing `list(b)`.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you! I added "update 2" in my question to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: No worries. But for Python 3 code you should be using [`bytes.fromhex(h)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex) instead of `binascii.unhexlify(h)`. It's a little more efficient, since it's a built-in classmethod of `bytes`.