# Unpack Bytes into String with Struct

Tags: python, string, byte

I am unpacking a binary file into a named tuple. A section of the bytes needs rolled into a string. How do I import a section of my binary data into a string within a namedtuple for the following binary data?

b'\x07\x01\x03\x00,\x02\x02\x00\x01\x00\x00\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01SRU 21-11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

I have tried using ord() to populate the string when I get to the bytes

```
import struct
from collections import namedtuple

with open("55613.rtu", "rb") as infile:
    Student = namedtuple('Student', "RtuVersion RtuInPod SlaveRtu RtuStatus PodNumber MeterType IsNonExistPod "
                                    "WellheadConfigWMvt1 WellheadConfigWMvt2 WellheadConfigWMvt3 "
                                    "DisplayMvtProcessDataTypeStatus1 DisplayMvtProcessDataTypeStatus2 "
                                    "DisplayMvtProcessDataTypeStatus3 "
                                    "AlarmEnableSet1 AlarmEnableSet2 AlarmEnableSet3 "
                                    "GetSaveEUTrendDataNoMatterWhat "
                                    "DoesRtuRequestTrendData ScanningNode Name")
    bytes = infile.read(52)
    x = struct.unpack('<BbbbhB????????????B%sp' % ord(bytes[20]), bytes)
```

So far, I am getting "TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found"

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19897878/3911355 (It says your call to ord() in Python 3 is reduntant and should be removed. Indexing a bytes object in Py3 returns an int.)

Comment: Thank you, I removed the ord() function and changed "%sp" to "32s" so the unpack formatter is "<BbbbhB????????????B32s"

Comment: And did that do the trick? Could you edit your question dump/print "bytes" prior to the attempted unpack if you are having further issues please.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick